# How to get IAM Policy using Google API billing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I'm working on GoogleCloud API, Which I would like to get all member and role of billing account.
I'm following on https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudbilling/latest/billing_v1/services.html
By using the Google API

```
billing_v1.CloudBillingClient().get_iam_policy()
```

Which I already have crendetials as file. I'm confuse on parameter **resource** what the value of parameter take it. The example explain like `projects/{project}` but I don't understand what the `{project}` is mean?
Before, I was used this gcloud sdk, for getting list.

```
gcloud beta billing accounts get-iam-policy <ACCOUNT_ID>
```

It's work fine but when I back to work with google API by following the below.

```
billing_v1.CloudBillingClient(credentials = credentials).get_iam_policy(resource="projects/xxxx/xxx")
```

It's look doesn't work still got error.

Please anyone have idea, How to use this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I Found just used **billingAccounts/xxx-xxx-xxx** It's work.

```
billing_v1.CloudBillingClient(credentials = credentials).get_iam_policy(resource="billingAccounts/xxx-xxx-xxx")
```

Why the documents is mentioned to **projects/{project}** doesn't understand it. TT

Comment: I had open issue already, https://github.com/googleapis/python-billing/issues/24